# jQuery cannot find the parent

Tags: jquery, html

This is what I am trying to get: when you click `#edit` jQuery finds in the closest `tr` the td called `#collapse`, and replaces its content with an input which has as value the previous `#collapse` html.
I tried on jsFiddle without any success: http://jsfiddle.net/8PDdn/1/

Can anyone help me to get what I wanted to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preventDefault()` is one of the methods of the `event` object not the selected element, you should call it for the `event` object instead, also you can use the  `blur` event of the input for modifying contents of the div tag after editing:

```
$(function() {   
    $("a#edit").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var currentTodo = $("#collapse");
        var cVal = currentTodo.html();
        currentTodo.html('<input type="text" name="description" value="'+ cVal +'">');
    });

    $(document).on('blur', '#collapse input', function(){
        $(this).parent().html(this.value)
    })
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8PDdn/6/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(this).preventDefault();
```

That isn't how you prevent the default event. You need to pass the event to the callback.

```
$(function() {

    $("a#edit").click(function(e) {
        $(e).preventDefault();
        var currentTodo = $(this).closest("tr").find("#collapse");
        var cVal = currentTodo.html();
        currentTodo.html('<input type="text" name="description" value="'+ cVal +'">');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things are wrong here:

1. `id` should be unique, you have many elements with the same id, change it to class.
2. your problem is caused by this:

   ```
   $("a#edit").click(function() {
       $(this).preventDefault(); ---> there is no preventDefault method on this
      ...
   });
   ```

you need to change it to:

```
$("a#edit").click(function(e) {
        $(e).preventDefault();
       ...
    });
```